# "Please upgrade your python" when installing numpy...when I have Python 3.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, pip

So, for starters, I installed pip. I ran "import pip" in my Python 3.8.1 shell and it recognized it; no error message. Then, to install numpy in terminal, I run the lines:

pip install numpy

and this is what I get:

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (1.8.0rc1)

Comment: You may have a Python 2.7 installed next to your Python 3.8.1.

Comment: What OS are you using? What version of Python does ˋpythonˋ point to? On most systems, ˋpipˋ is associated with ˋpythonˋ, which in turn is Python 2.7. Do you have a separate ˋpip3ˋ and ˋpython3ˋ executable?

Comment: If you run `head $(which pip)`, you'll see that `pip` is a script being run by a Python 2.7 interpreter. It doesn't "know" that you meant to install `numpy` for some other Python 3 installation.

Comment: Thank you chepner, MisterMayagi and Trilarion for the helpful feedback the error was because I used pip instead of pip3.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `python3 -m pip install numpy`.

Comment: Thank you! This appears to have worked. I had seen the suggestion before and tried it, but the right things hadn't been installed beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The 2.7 is referring to the version installed on your computer, which is referenced by default when 'python' is invoked. You should consider creating virtual environments, that way you can run multiple versions of python on your computer and still only access the interpreter as 'python'. Python 3 has to be accessed with 'python3' unless you're in a virtual environment.